# In my Androidstudio music player pause button problem

Tags: java, android-studio-3.0, android-music-player

When I press the pause button and then press the play button song plays from the pause position. But when the song ends and then press the play button song plays from the pause position, not from the starting.

Pasting my code here

```
 public void play(View view){
    if(mediaPlayer==null) {

        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ennasona);
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }

    else if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){

        int nowMusicPosition = 0;

        if (nowMusicPosition == mediaPlayer.getDuration()){

            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ennasona);
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
        else {
            mediaPlayer.seekTo(pauseCurrentPosition);
            mediaPlayer.start();
            nowMusicPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();

        }
    }
}
public void pause(View view){

    if(mediaPlayer!=null) {

        mediaPlayer.pause();

        pauseCurrentPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();

    }
}
public   void stop(View view){

    if (mediaPlayer!=null)

    mediaPlayer.stop();

    mediaPlayer = null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the API I would say you're doing it too complicated. You don't have to remember the position, because if you're pausing the playback, the MediaPlayer should remember the position itself.

So just use play(), pause() and you're safe. Don't seek().

The problems with your code are here:

```
else if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
    // this is called nowMusicPosition, down there you've used pauseCurrentPosition
    // this always gets 0, never changes
    int nowMusicPosition = 0;
    if (nowMusicPosition == mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()){
         // now you're recreating the MediaPlayer. why?
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ennasona);
        mediaPlayer.start();
    } else {
        // if video at its end gets stopped, the
        // getCurrentPosition() delivers the last
        // position in the video and you get down
        // here and you're seeking to the paused
        // position again
        mediaPlayer.seekTo(pauseCurrentPosition);
        mediaPlayer.start();
        // now you're setting nowMusicPosition, but it gets 0 again if pressing play again, see above
        nowMusicPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
    }
}
```

Comment: The reference with all the possible states: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer

Comment: Thank you for your response. Thank you for showing the problems in my code :)

Comment: Because I'm using stop button I need to use seekto.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with this condition.

```
if (nowMusicPosition == mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()){

        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ennasona);

    }
```

This is not executing. Recheck it.
Even you don't need to recreate the media player instance just use this

```
mediaPlayer.start();
```

for playing from the start after completing.

Hope this will help you.